# Tag badge not awarded due to merged answer?

Tags: support, tag-badges, merged-questions

On July 27th I answered the question [Is unit testing alone ever a good reason to expose private instance variables via getters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31646092/2422776) that was tagged with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [unit-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing), and received quite a few upvotes.

A day later, a moderator merged this question into [Making a private method public to unit test it…good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7075938/2422776), which is tagged with  [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [unit-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) and [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). This merging pushed my c# tag score well over 100, and I expected to get a bronze tag badge for it.

I'm aware of the fact these things take time, and that these badges are awarded by batch processes, but I don't think this is the issue here - it's been over a week since the merge, a weekend has passed, and even the data explorer got updated and is showing me a tag score in excess of 100.
Is it an intentional behavior to not count votes on merged questions towards tag badges, have I stumbled over a bug, or am I just being impatient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your score more than qualifies... But you only have 8 answers, and the badge requires at least 20.

Comment: Lesson learnt: Always read the fine print. Wow, that was stupid on my behalf. Thanks Shog!